# Saving an array to separate rows in a mySQL database without knowing number of rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, web, relational-database

I am working on a hashtag system that allows users to use hashtags in an article post. I sort out all the hashtagged words using `preg_match_all('/#([\p{L}\p{Mn}]+)/u',$t,$matches);` which reads them into an array. What I need to do is store each of the hashtagged words into a row in a mySQL database so they can be searched for the most common ones to build a type of trending system.

I'm having issues storing my array into separate rows in my database, and I'm also confused as to how to do it without knowing how many rows I would need because each article would have a different amount of hashtagged words. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT - I came up with a loop, but now it keeps reading the word Array into my database, 
foreach($matches as $a => $b) {
        $query1 = "INSERT INTO hashtags (hashtags) VALUES ('$matches[$a]');";

$q = mysql_query($query1) or die ('Error posting data');

}
Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a loop to go over every item you want to insert.

Comment: That makes sense - how would I go about structuring that? I'm a little lost on how to format the mysql query.

Comment: There is a ton of info on that subject, literally 1000's of question have been asked and answered already, see this search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+[mysql]+insert  **Oh and use PDO to communicate with MySQL**, see: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-insert-statement.htm & http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0140__Insert-Update-Delete/0020__Insert.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here i have made some example for inset row in sql.

```
$t= "<b>example: </b><div align=left>this is a test</div>";

$matches = array();

preg_match_all('|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|U',$t,$matches);
print_r($matches);

for ($i=0; $i<count($matches);$i++)
{
    for ($k=0; $k<count($matches[$i]);$k++)
    {
        $arrayKeyword[] = array($matches[$i][$k]);
    }
    $value = implode(",",$arrayKeyword);
    $sql = "Insert into <tablename> value (".$value.")";
}
```